# How can I send an email every 8 hours that sends a attachment after a specific amount of time

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am having trouble with this specific function , i am trying to call the "send_email" function below so that it sends an email every 8 hours, The email contains an attachment in the form of a .txt file that records user data. In the body of the email I have a Header that displays the time and date. In the header i also need the time and date to be update to the current time that the email is sent. Here is the

When looking for a solution ive tried using the time.sleep() method and putting it inside my function and wrapping the function in a while True: loop. but this interfered with the data that was collected in the .txt file , user input was not recorded. I do not need the function to run at a specific time each day, but run every hour from when I run the .py file
This is the function i used to write the email:

```
def send_email(filename, attachment, toaddr):
    fromaddr = email_address

    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    msg['From'] = fromaddr

    msg['To'] = toaddr

    msg['Subject'] = "Retreat Log"

    body = Header

    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

    filename = filename
    attachment = open(attachment, 'rb')
    p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    p.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(p)

    p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

    msg.attach(p)

    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)

    s.starttls()

    s.login(fromaddr, password)

    text = msg.as_string()

    s.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)

    s.quit()
```

This is how the body of my email records the current date and time, this is taken from the time library.

```
datetime = time.ctime(time.time())
Header = f'Date/Time: {datetime}\n'
```

This is the method i tried that did not work:

```
while True:
def send_email(filename, attachment, toaddr): ...
time.sleep(8)
```

Comment: to sleep for 8h : you should try time.sleep(28800) , time sleep is in seconds that's why it did not work as expected

Comment: I would strongly recomend that you split the task (send email) from the scheduling. Create a send email script and then use an external scheduler like `chron` to run it on the desired schedule. It's much easier than trying to write and debug your won scheduler

Comment: Look into using an AWS Lambda function that runs off a scheduler set in AWS Event Bridge. This allows you to not have a server running 24/7 only to run every 8 hours.